# getting an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, not sure why

Tags: vb.net, add-in, office-interop

Below is the full function, but this is the area of the code that I believe is causing the error:

EDIT: After stepping through the function it looks like the second time around the loop taskItem is equal to nothing even after being set to "taskrequestItem.GetAssociatedTask(False)", so in that instance of the loop the first time taskItem is refered to ie. if taskitem.categories = "TTD" then the exception is thrown. However, I added the condition of "AND taskItem IsNot Nothing" to the if statement, and I still get this exception.

```
If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._TaskRequestItem) Then
                            counter += 1
                            taskrequestItem = resultItem
                            taskItem = taskrequestItem.GetAssociatedTask(False)
                            'taskItem.PercentComplete = 10
                            'If Not (taskItem.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskComplete) Then
                            'strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                            '" 2duedate: " + )

                            If taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
                            TTDcounter += 1
                            Dim listarray() As String = {taskItem.Delegator, taskItem.Subject, taskItem.DueDate, stripEstComp(taskItem.Body.ToString())}
                            taskPaneControl3.ListView2.Items.Add("New").SubItems.AddRange(listarray)
                            End If

                        End If
                'End If
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem)
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
                    Loop Until IsNothing(resultItem)
```

The error started popping up after I added the part that fetches the associated taskitem from each taskrequestitem.

```
Private Sub GetTaskRequests(objApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)
    Dim folder As Outlook.Folder = _
    TryCast(Application.Session.Folders(email).Folders("Inbox"), Outlook.Folder)

    Dim searchCriteria As String = "[MessageClass] = 'IPM.TaskRequest'"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim taskrequestItem As Outlook.TaskRequestItem = Nothing
    Dim taskItem As Outlook.TaskItem = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
    Dim TTDcounter As Integer = 0

    Try
        folderItems = folder.Items
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        If (folderItems.Count > 0) Then
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
            If Not IsNothing(resultItem) Then
                strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
                Do
                    If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._TaskRequestItem) Then
                        counter += 1
                        taskrequestItem = resultItem
                        taskItem = taskrequestItem.GetAssociatedTask(False)
                        'taskItem.PercentComplete = 10
                        'If Not (taskItem.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskComplete) Then
                        'strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                        '" 2duedate: " + )

                        'If taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
                        TTDcounter += 1
                        Dim listarray() As String = {taskItem.Delegator, taskItem.Subject, taskItem.DueDate, stripEstComp(taskItem.Body.ToString())}
                        taskPaneControl3.ListView2.Items.Add("New").SubItems.AddRange(listarray)
                        'End If

                    End If
            'End If
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem)
            resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
                Loop Until IsNothing(resultItem)
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                               folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Debug.WriteLine("gettaskrequest")

    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try single-stepping through your code? It should narrow down the line(s) causing the error.

Comment: After stepping through the function it looks like the second time around the loop taskItem is equal to nothing even after being set to "taskrequestItem.GetAssociatedTask(False)", so in that instance of the loop the first time taskItem is refered to ie. if taskitem.categories = "TTD" then the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I added the condition of "AND taskItem IsNot Nothing" to the if statement, and I still get this exception.

Thad would still check

```
If taskItem.Categories = "TTD"
```

first. The test for `taskItem isNot Nothing` needs to be done first, and you need a short-circuiting logical `And`, that would be

```
If taskItem isNot Nothing AndAlso taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
If taskItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso taskItem.Categories = "TTD" Then
```

Without the [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operator the evaluation of the condition will continue checking the taskItem.Categories and your code will crash. Of course, in this case, the order of evaluation makes a big difference.